# TastyPie how to access objects Manager methods?

Tags: python, django

Using TastyPie's `obj_create` method I want to overwrite the bundle save and call my model object Manager method`create_member()` but I get the following error when attempting to do so :

```
Manager isn't accessible via MemberParticipant instances
```

How in TastyPie can I access my objects Manager methods? bundle.obj does not seem to have access!

**Tried:**

```
def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
    bundle.obj = self._meta.object_class()
    bundle.obj.objects.create_member(stuff)
 return bundle
```

**Model:**

```
class MemberManager(models.Manager):
    def create_member(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves new Member Participant with the given email, password and account.
        """
        time_now = timezone.now()
        stuff here


class MemberParticipant(AbstractParticipant):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    objects = MemberManager()
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'participants'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On django model object there is `_default_manager` property which stores the default object manager instance. You can try to use that.

```
>>> m=Model1.objects.all()[0]
>>> m._default_manager
<django.db.models.manager.Manager object at 0x2a38b90>
>>>
```

However, I'm not sure how this behaves with tasypie.

Comment: Nope, did not seem to like that either. Why can I not access this manager tho? Does Tatypie have any special ticks? from looking at the tastypie code obj is just = to the class so obj.objects should work right?

Comment: @GrantU, If `obj` is class/model then `obj.objects` should work.

Comment: yep it should darn it.

Comment: @GrantU, you are overwriting `bundle.obj` in your method, that may cause the problem.

Comment: tried with and without the meta.object_class object. bundles: http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/bundles.html

Comment: Ok, I have decided to remove the Manager, since thinking and reading more it kinda does not make any sense. obj is already a member, so why would you want to create one from the class?

Comment: @GrantU, Agree, but the doc says `bundle.obj` may not be saved yet, so you can still create object using your manager and skip tastypie's.